# Set duration of 'newpassword' link validity via config/general?

Tags: config, password

Is it possible to modify how long the 'newpassword' links are valid for via a setting in config/general.php?

(I've found `defaultTokenDuration` but it sounds like this might only be for the live preview tokens?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting you're looking for is `verificationCodeDuration` which defaults to 24 hours (86400 seconds).

https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-config-generalconfig.html#verificationcodeduration

(And see craft\helpers\ConfigHelper::durationInSeconds() for a list of supported value types)

Comment: Feel free to mark your own as the accepted answer! ;)

Comment: Ha thanks @RitterKnight I do love being right, rarely as it does happen :)